# Can mana from The Seedcore be used to cast Greven, Predator Captain

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I have a copy of [Greven, Predator Captain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=470589) that says his creature type is Human Warrior. I know that he is a Phyrexian in-lore, and the link says his creature type is Phyrexian Human Warrior. Does this mean that I could use mana generated by [The Seedcore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=602789)'s second ability:

> {T}: Add one mana of any color. Spend this mana only to cast Phyrexian creature spells.

to cast Greven, even though the card itself does not give him the Phyrexian sub-type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, Greven, Predator Captain is Phyrexian, so you can cast him using mana generated by The Seedcore.**

[Rule 108.1](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Card) says

> Use the Oracle card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

The link [Greven, Predator Captain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Greven%2C%20Predator%20Captain) shows the most official and up-to-date information about the card's text. That page says that the card is Phyrexian, so it is.